# If $X= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} X_n$ and $X_n=Y_n$ everywhere and $Y_n= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} Y$ then is X=Y a.s

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

$X= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} X_n$ and $X_n=Y_n$ everywhere(for every $n$) and $Y_n= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} Y$ then X=Y a.s where the limits are in $L^2$

My attempt
We can pass along to a sub-subsequence  to conclude(since convergence in $L^2$ implies convergence almost surely along a subsequence)
$X=\lim\limits_{k \to \infty}X_{n_{m_k}}=\lim\limits_{k \to \infty}Y_{n_{m_k}}=Y$

Comment: Just make sure you use the same subsequence for both $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$. Then you are fine.

Comment: Perfect thank you very much